# (iOs SpriteKit)passing a sprite in a method

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to make a parallax effect on my background title screen with mountains moving. The "trick" i want to make is when a mountain goes to the end of the screen, instead of destroying the node and create it again at the begining position, i just want to change it's position to the begining position and loop the rest of actions. For this i create my moutain sprite at the begining of the createSceneContents() function and i pass the sprite to a method animate() wich do allways the same combo of actions forever: animate to the right, then when it's at x position, change mountain.position.x to the begining...

```
-(void)createSceneContents{

//crear
SKSpriteNode *mountain = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"mountain.png"];
mountain.name = @"mountain";
//initial position
mountain.position = CGPointMake(-161.5,15);
//animate
SKAction *animRight = [SKAction moveToX:801.5 duration:4];

SKAction *comboActions = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction performSelector:@selector(animate:mountain) onTarget:@"mountain"]];
```

And here i have my method declaration:

```
    - (void) animate:(SKSpriteNode*)mountain
{
      // code....
}
```

My problem is i'm allways having errors passing the SKSpriteNode *mountain in my method and
I'm going crazy trying everithing.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid performSelector action, using a custom action like this.

```
SKAction* parallaxMoveAction = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction moveToX:801.5 duration:4.0f],[SKAction customActionWithDuration:0 actionBlock:^(SKNode* node, CGFloat elapsedTime){
            [node setPosition:CGPointMake(-161.5,15)];
        }]]];
```

If you set custom action duration to 0 it will be performed only once.

On the other hand your perform selector action should look like this:

```
[SKAction performSelector:@selector(animate:) onTarget:self]
```

As far as i know you can't pass arguments to it.